# Retrieve unique characters from 2 strings

Tags: python

I would like to retrieve "ed" from these strings ("abce", "abcd") because they are unique letters when compared to each other. How can I fix my codes? Thanks.

```
def solve(a,b):
    box = []
    for i in a:
        for j in b:
            if i != j and i not in box:
                box.append(i)
    return ''.join(box)

print(solve("abce","abcd")) < ----- Answer : abce
```

Comment: you don' need to iterate over both, just iterate on the first and ask if any given character is on the other with `i not in b`... or just use set operations...

Comment: @Copperfield If you only iterate over `a`, you won't get `d` in the result.

Comment: @Barmar right, well then iterate on the first and when finish then iterate on the second... point is you don't do nested loop...

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the strings to sets, then find the characters that aren't in the intersection.

```
def solve(a, b):
    seta = set(a)
    setb = set(b)
    return "".join(seta.union(setb).difference(seta.intersection(setb))
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to convert the strings to sets and take the [symmetric difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference):

```
s1 = "abce"
s2 = "abcd"

''.join(set(s1) ^ set(s2))
# 'de'

# or
''.join(set(s1).symmetric_difference(s2))
# same result
```

Answer (score 1):

Another straightforward solution (which doesn't involve sets):

```
def solve(a, b):
    return ''.join(ch for ch in a+b if not (ch in a and ch in b))


print(solve("abce", "abcd"))
```

It's not more efficient, but it like it because it's brief, clear and literally reads like what it needs to do.

For every character in a and b, add it to the result if it's not in both a and b.